# TSQL - DateTime difference between more than two rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to find out how to calculate difference between multiple rows from one simple query. Here it is:

```
SELECT [DateTime],EmployeeId,ControlPointID,EventTypeID
FROM   [Events]
WHERE  Day([DateTime]) = 4
       AND Month([DateTime]) = 7
       AND Year([DateTime]) = 2017
       AND EmployeeId = 451
       AND ControlPointID IN ( 3, 6 )
       AND EventTypeID IN ( 1, 2 )
       ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

Result:

```
    DateTime                  EmployeeId    ControlPointID  EventTypeID
    2017-07-04 11:32:10.000   451           6               1
    2017-07-04 16:07:00.000   451           3               2
    2017-07-04 16:42:50.000   451           6               1
    2017-07-04 20:04:10.000   451           3               2
```

I need to calculate difference between `[DateTime]` in minutes.
`EventTypeId = 1` means that `Employee` enters to the building and `EventTypeId=2` means that Employee leaves. I can calculate difference between first Enter Event and last Leave Event. In this case it's 512 minutes. But, i have problem to calculate work time, when someone enters twice and leaves twice. It should be 477 minutes. Calculation should looks like this:

```
    DateDiff = (2017-07-04 16:07:00.000 - 2017-07-04 11:32:10.000) +
               (2017-07-04 20:04:10.000 - 2017-07-04 16:42:50.000)
```

Can you help me figure it out, please ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given a building entry, finding the first leave after that entry can be done with [`cross apply`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql#using-apply):

```
select entry.EmployeeId, entry.DateTime, exit.DateTime
from Events entry
  cross apply (select top 1 e.DateTime
               from Events e
               where e.EmployeeId = entry.EmployeeId
                 and e.DateTime > entry.DateTime
                 and e.EventTypeId = 2
               order by e.DateTime asc
              ) as exit
where entry.EventTypeId = 1
```

at which point you just need to use the [applicable T/SQL function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql) to get the difference in whatever unit you want (eg. in minutes with `datediff(minute, entry.DateTime, exit.DateTime)`.

To get the total of all the differences simply sum the differences:

```
select EmployeeId, sum(mins)
from (
    select entry.EmployeeId, entry.DateTime as EntryDateTime, exit.DateTime as ExitDateTime, datediff(minute, EntryDateTime, ExitDateTime) as mins
    from Events entry
      cross apply (select top 1 e.DateTime
                   from Events e
                   where e.EmployeeId = entry.EmployeeId
                     and e.DateTime > entry.DateTime
                     and e.EventTypeId = 2
                   order by e.DateTime asc
                  ) as exit
    where entry.EventTypeId = 1
) as input
group by EmployeeId
```

Edit: added overall summation (with diff on the inside for clarity)

Comment: Right. Idea is correct. It's because I described problem very poorly. @Richard see my edition

Comment: Fixed the `order by` to `asc` to get correct result hope you don't mind

Comment: @Pரதீப் No problem: I don't know how I manage to get the ordering the wrong way on first pass 90% of the time in cases like this :-)

Comment: @fanarek summation added (kept the inner query separate the the natural need to change this to be by employee *by day*.

Comment: Again missed `Group By` ;)

Comment: @Richard it works, but It should returns daily summations.

Comment: @Richard, Nevermind, forgot to change where clause. It works perfect. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using `LAG` window function, since 2008 does not supports it we need to `left join` with `Row_Number` to find the previous entry

```
;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT Row_number()OVER(Partition by EmployeeID ORDER BY [DateTime]) rn,*
         FROM   Yourresult)
SELECT a.EmployeeID, 
       Sum(Datediff(minute, b.[DateTime], a.[DateTime]))
FROM   cte a
       LEFT JOIN cte b
              ON a.EmployeeID = b.EmployeeID 
             AND a.rn = b.rn + 1
WHERE  a.[EventTypeId] = 2 
GROUP BY a.EmployeeID
```

**Note :** This considers there isn't any wrong punches. Just like your sample data

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Like Richard's answer, idea is corrent, but it's not what I really need. I think you misunderstood me because I described problem very poorly. @Pரதீப் see my edition

Comment: @fanarek - It does that.. http://rextester.com/BSBVMS91873 check the demo expected result is coming

Comment: Thanks. It looks like it does, but what if there's much more records in [Events] table ?